# Cannot connect Tableau to presto on emr

Tags: tableau-api, emr, presto

I cannot connect Tableau to presto on an EMR cluster. 
Versions: Tableau 10, emr-5.3.0, Presto 0.157.1

I am able to connect via the presto-cli using the commands

```
[hadoop@ip-172-xx-yy-zz scripts]$ presto-cli
presto> use hive.poc;
presto:poc> show tables;
        Table
...
```

But I am not ablewhen trying to connect from tableau using the Teradata ODBC connector. I am getting the error "catalog is not specified" as a result.

But, when inspecting the trace of the java error, available at the Presto web interface (http://ec2-aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd.eee.compute.amazonaws.com:8889/query.html?20170130_165412_00329_5gbba), I get the following error. It looks more as a parsing error.

```
com.facebook.presto.sql.parser.ParsingException: line 1:1: no viable alternative at input '{'
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.parser.SqlParser$1.syntaxError(SqlParser.java:45)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.ProxyErrorListener.syntaxError(ProxyErrorListener.java:65)
    ... 60 more
```

The submitted query was the following:

```
{"query":"select * from \"hive.poc\".\"information_schema\".\"tables\" WHERE table_schema LIKE 'default' AND table_name LIKE '*'","preparedStatements":{}}
```

Any help / hint will be appreciated.

**Note:** in the EMR cluster, the presto server is available in port 8889, not in the usual 8080.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Tableau is using the Teradata drivers (at least that's what the Tableau website tells you to install). Version 1.1.8 of the drivers is only compatible with Presto 0.157t (i.e. the Teradata release of 0.157).

This is the specific pull request responsible for the error you're seeing: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/pull/5868. A solution would probably be to install 0.157t on EMR but this requires a lot more work than simply checking the Presto box when spinning up a cluster on EMR.

**A workaround that fixes the issue introduced by pull request 5868:**

In the aws emr command add the --configurations flag and point to a local json file. For example:

```
aws emr create-cluster [...] --configurations file://./clusterConfiguration.json
```

With the contents of clusterConfiguration.json being:

```
{
  "Classification": "presto-config",
  "Properties": {
    "presto.version": "0.148"
  }
}
```

This sets the published version of presto to 0.148. This is picked up by the Teradata drivers, which then use the old payload that 0.157 expects.

Comment: Were you able to connect with this modification? I wasn't able to create a new cluster with the Presto-0.148 version even specifying the configuration file as you recommended.
The only way to create a cluster with the Presto version 0.148 was with an emr-4.7 cluster. After creating it, we ware still not able to connect from Tableau.

Comment: Yes, this works for us. You shouldn't create a cluster with 0.148 but you should tell Presto to set it's version string to 0.148 even it you're using 0.157 or 0.166 on EMR. So when the drivers connect to the cluster, they read the version string and 'think' that they're connecting to 0.148. If you follow the steps above this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Presto on EMR by default uses Hive as its catalog. Try to enter into the presto-cli using a command like this
 presto-cli --catalog hive

Then you should be able to access all the tables. Also in tableau you might have to define hive as the catalog.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am able to connect via presto-cli. My problem is when trying to establish the connection from Tableau. It does not recognise the hive catalog

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem.

Using rest-client , I changed the submitted query to be only the SQL statement, without the json envelope, and it worked. It doesn't resolves the problem, but it gives a hint for a solution.